# `if let` does not run destructor if intermediary value

Tags: rust, destructor

Consider two semantically equivalent pieces of code:

```rust
let x = Mutex::new(0);
if *x.lock().unwrap() == 0 {
    *x.lock().unwrap() = 1;
}
```

```rust
let x = Mutex::new(0);
if let 0 = *x.lock().unwrap() {
    *x.lock().unwrap() = 1;
}
```

The first one runs as expected, while the second one deadlocks. Why is guard destructor being run by `if` but not by `if let`? Where can I find documentation on this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found on [`docs.rust-lang.org`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/). Specifically refer to [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/if-expr.html#if-let-expressions) article, where it's said that:

> An `if let` expression is equivalent to a `match` expression as follows:
>
> `if let PATS = EXPR { /* body */ } else { /*else */ }`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> `match EXPR { PATS => { /* body */ }, _ => { /* else */ } }`

After heading to the [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html) article, it's said that

> A match behaves differently depending on whether or not the scrutinee expression is a *place expression* or *value expression*.
>
> If the scrutinee expression is a value expression, it is first evaluated into a temporary location, and the resulting value is sequentially compared to the patterns in the arms until a match is found. The first arm with a matching pattern is chosen as the branch target of the match, any variables bound by the pattern are assigned to local variables in the arm's block, and control enters the block.
>
> ... more about place expressions

In your case the scrutinee `*x.lock().unwrap()` is a value expression, thus the guard's lifetime is the same as the lifetime of your main branch. Thus you get a deadlock, trying to `.lock()` mutex again after it's already locked by your own `if let`